# Spring-Data-Jpa OneToMany query duplicate ids in the info log?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I don't understand why the ids are duplicated (id_msg, id_pers_acct), that's what's in my Springboot log :

```
select personneco0_.id_pers_acct as id_pers_1_2_0_,
…
from test.person_account personacc0_ where personacc0_.id_pers_acct=?

select messages0_.id_pers_acct as id_pers_5_1_0_, 
messages0_.id_msg as id_msg1_1_0_, 
messages0_.id_msg as id_msg1_1_1_, 
messages0_.content as content2_1_1_, 
messages0_.date as date3_1_1_, 
messages0_.id_pers_acct_person_account as id_pers_4_1_1_, 
messages0_.id_pers_acct as id_pers_5_1_1_ 
from test.message messages0_ where messages0_.id_pers_acct=?
```

In my entity PersonAccount i have this code :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<Message> messages = new HashSet <Message>();
```

In my entity Message i have this code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE", catalog = "TEST")
public class Message implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -602563072975023074L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID_MSG")
Long idMsg;
@Column(name = "CONTENT")
String content;
@Column(name = "DATE")
Date date;
@Column(name = "ID_PERS_ACCT", nullable = false) 
Long sender;
@Column(name = "ID_PERS_ACCT_PERSON_ACCOUNT", nullable = false) 
Long receiver;
```

In my RestController, i call this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
 public PersonAccount getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
 return userRepository.getOne(id);
}
```

Comment: could be getOne(Id) method , try findOne(id) because getOne() not return actual entity.

Comment: no it does not change anything

Comment: What's the actual error?  You've put in the code and the log of what was executed, but you haven't put in the actual error.

Comment: There's no error log, I'm just wondering about the information log